# Excel formula not calculating, formula calculation is set to automatic, all cells are set to general not text and tried ctrl shift alt F9

Tags: excel, formula, calculation

Using formula =IFERROR(SUMIFS($H$2:$H$493,$B$2:$B$493,B572,$C$2:$C$493,C572,$D$2:$D$493,D572),0). This formula works fine in every other worksheet but sheet4. It also works in a couple of cells and not all. I have made sure the formula calculations is set to automatic, the cells are not text and are set to general, no spaces in the formulas, re-entered the formulas, retyped all data in sheet, tried ctrl shift alt F9 and vba code Call Application.CalculateFullRebuild. I am stumped. Could it be that my workbook is overloaded with data and formulas, having over 26,000 formulas written that is?

Comment: Welcome to SO! It is not a matter of formulas. Did you try to copy your worksheet to another one and try it there?

Comment: Thanks and yes, I've tried it in another workbook as well.

Comment: So that one looks as there is one hidden issue with your format. 26000 formulas is not a big thing on Excel. Could you upload one sample?

Comment: Try on Google drive

Comment: https://drive.google.com/open?id=153Ypa7vPEbYALEp525keZSHIh0qM7U1w

Comment: The problem is in row 572 - 657 column E

Comment: The issue is that your original data, from row 2 to row 493, it have an space at the end of RENTAL, so you have `"RENTAL "` instead of `"RENTAL"`. Some other items simply not exist... so I am supposing that you are working on it.

Comment: Wow! That was very hidden. The first time I hit control F, typed RENTAL and replaced all with RENTAL and that did not work. But like you said, when I hit ctrl F and typed RENTAL and then a space and replaced with RENTAL with no space it fixed it. Thanks so much!